# inline assembly error: can't find a register in class 'GENERAL_REGS' while reloading 'asm'

Tags: xcode, gcc, assembly, constraints, inline-assembly

I have an inline **AT&T** style assembly block, which works with **XMM** registers and there are no problems in **Release** configuration of my **XCode** project, however I've stumbled upon this strange error (which is supposedly a **GCC** bug) in **Debug** configuration... Can I fix it somehow? There is nothing special in assembly code, but I am using a lot of memory constraints (**12 constraints**), can this cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, sorry, but the comments section is too short for this ...

Can you post a sample `asm("..." :::)` line that demonstrates the problem ?

The use of XMM registers is not the issue, the error message indicates that GCC wanted to create code like, say:

```
movdqa (%rax),%xmm0
```

i.e. memory loads/stores through pointers held in general registers, and you specified more memory locations than available general-purpose regs (it's probably 12 in debug mode because because `RBP`, `RSP` are used for frame/stackpointer and likely `RBX` for the global offset table and `RAX` reserved for returns) without realizing register re-use potential.

You might be able to eek things out by doing something like:

```
void *all_mem_args_tbl[16] = { memarg1, memarg2, ... };
void *trashme;

asm ("movq (%0), %1\n\t"
     "movdqa (%1), %xmm0\n\t"
     "movq 8(%0), %1\n\t"
     "movdqa (%1), %xmm1\n\t"
     ...
     : "r"all_mem_args_tbl : "r"(trashme) : ...);
```

i.e. put all the mem locations into a table that you pass as operand, and then manage the actual general-purpose register use on your own. It might be two pointer accesses through the indirection table, but whether that makes a difference is hard to say without knowing your complete assembler code piece.

Answer (score 0):

The Debug configuration uses `-O0` by default. Since this flag disables optimisations, the compiler is probably not being able to allocate registers given the constraints specified by your inline assembly code, resulting in register starvation.

One solution is to specify a different optimisation level, e.g. `-Os`, which is the one used by default in the Release configuration.

Comment: @Ryan That’s odd. Check which is the command-line invocation issued when compiling the Release build and compare it against the corresponding Debug build invocation.

Comment: Well, the only difference between Debug and Release configurations is the usage of SSE3 / supplemental SSE3 instructions...

Comment: @Ryan Does it work if you enable SSE3 in the Debug configuration?

Comment: @Ryan It’d help if you edited your question and posted the actual command-line invocations for both configurations.

Comment: I can't edit my questions, because I am an unregistered user... In case of Release version the invocation is /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x c++ -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -Os -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -msse3 -mssse3 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -iquote...

Comment: In case of Debug configuration there are 2 differences - -mfix-and-continue argument and -O0 optimization flag even though the optimization is set to -Os in XCode configuration manager! Who is overriding my settings?

Comment: @Ryan `-mfix-and-continue` is used for dynamic loading of .o files in gdb, so the problem seems to be `-O0` indeed. I’m not sure why it’s not being used in your project, though. Do you have separate .xcconfig files?